# Redeclaration of global variables allowed in C?

Tags: c, variables, storage, global, declaration

Why is this code allowed in C?

```
int x;

int main() {
    printf("%d\n", x);
    return 0;
}

int x = 2;
```

It compiles without warnings using `-Wall -std=c89` with both `gcc` and `clang`.

I have previously thought that `int x` at global scope is equivalent to `int x = 0`. I find myself surprised.

Comment: @pablo1977 `x` **is** a static variable!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`int x;`, at file scope, is a *tentative definition* as well answered by [@PSkocik](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40075215/2410359) and will act like `int x = 0;` if a definition with initialization does not exist.

> I have previously thought that `int x` at global scope is equivalent to `int x = 0`.

The tricky part about a "global" `int x;` is assuming it is initialized with 0.  It is initialized with 0 if another `int x = constant;` does not exist in *any* compilation unit.

Therefore recommend explicit initialization and not counting on default initialization to 0 bits when the object needs initialization.

```
// Does an initialization exist, in some file -maybe?
int x;
// Better.  If another file initializes `x`, good to see a compiler/linker error.
int x = 0;
```

Comment: I don't think that this completely correct. Having one tentative definition in one TU and one with an initializer in another, is not covered by the standard. These are two contraticting definitions, and thus lead to UB. gcc does this as an extension, though, but other compilers might not.

Comment: @JensGustedt  Perhaps so.  Will review.

Answer (score -3):

```
int x;
```

Is a declaration.

```
int x = 2;
```

Is a definition (which is also a declaration).

Re-declaration is allowed as long as the declarations are compatible (the same).

```
int x;
int x;
```

Will work. Re-definition is not allowed

```
int x = 2;
int x = 2;
```

Will not work.
Use without a declaration before it or without a definition is disallowed

Comment: `int x;` at file-scope is a _tentative definition_. And `int x = 2;` is also a declaration.

Comment: @Olaf, yes, but as long as there is real definition, tentative definitions are irrelevant. As the name says, the are tentative, as long as no other comes along.

Comment: And names with external linkage should always have an `extern` declaration, best in a header file. Otherwise use internal linkage.

Comment: @JensGustedt: That's right. But it is always good to use the correct terms. OP apparently wonders that `int x;` alone also works, which my comment explains.

Comment: This is "technically correct": `int x;` is a declaration, and `int x=2;` is both a declaration and a definition. However it doesn't mention that `int x;` is also a definition, which is crucial to answering the question.